# didSelectViewController does not get called on certain occasions

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have the problem that many already have reported, `didSelectViewController` doesn't get called, but in my case it sometimes gets called. I have three tabs and three view controllers. Every time user presses second or third tab I need to execute some code. In my SecondViewController and ThirdViewController I have:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
[tabBarController setDelegate:self];
```

Now everything works fine with the SecondViewController, the `didSelectViewController` gets called every time the second tab is pressed. Also in ThirdViewController `didSelectViewController`gets called every time the third tab is pressed but only when second bar is meanwhile not pressed. So when I switch back and forth between FirstViewController and ThirdViewController everything is OK. But when I go in a pattern like first->second->third, then `didSelectViewController` doesn't get called in ThirdViewController. Also when I go like first->third->second->third `didSelectViewController` gets called in ThirdViewController the first time but not the second time. Any ideas?

Comment: I happened to notice your comment on my answer before you deleted it, and I have edited my answer with a few hints how to integrate the example code in your project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to follow what exactly you are doing, but from what I understand you are responding to tab switches by changing the `UITabBarController`'s delegate back and forth between `SecondViewController` and `ThirdViewController`.

If that is true, I would advise against doing this. Instead I would suggest you try the following:

- Assign a delegate that never changes. For a start you could use your app delegate, but it would probably be better if you had a dedicated small class for this. I am sure that now you have a non-changing delegate, it will get 100% of all the calls to `tabBarController: didSelectViewController:`.
- The object that is the delegate must have a reference to both the `SecondViewController` and `ThirdViewController` instances. If you are designing your UI with Interface Builder, you might do this by adding two `IBOutlet`s to the delegate class and connecting the appropriate instances to the outlets.
- Now when the delegate receives `tabBarController: didSelectViewController:` it can simply forward the notification to either `SecondViewController` or `ThirdViewController`, depending on which of the tabs was selected.

A basic code example:

```
// TabBarControllerDelegate.h file
@interface TabBarControllerDelegate : NSObject <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet SecondViewController* secondViewController;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ThirdViewController* thirdViewController;


// TabBarControllerDelegate.m file
- (void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController*)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController
{
    if (viewController == self.secondViewController)
      [self.secondViewController doSomething];
    else if (viewController == self.thirdViewController)
      [self.thirdViewController doSomethingElse];
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Some hints on how to integrate the example code from above into your project:

- Add an instance of `TabBarControllerDelegate` to the .xib file that also contains the `TabBarController`
- Connect the `delegate` outlet of `TabBarController`'  to the `TabBarControllerDelegate` instance
- Connect the `secondViewController` outlet of `TabBarControllerDelegate` to the `SecondViewController` instance
- Connect the `thirdViewController` outlet of `TabBarControllerDelegate` to the `ThirdViewController` instance
- Add a method `- (void) doSomething` to `SecondViewController`
- Add a method `- (void) doSomethingElse` to `ThirdViewController`
- Make sure that you don't have any code left in `SecondViewController` and `ThirdViewController` changes the `TabBarController` delegate!

Once you are all set and everything is working fine, you will probably want to cleanup a bit:

- Change the names of the notification methods `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` to something more sensible
- If you followed the discussion in the comments, maybe you also want to get rid of the `secondViewController` and `thirdViewController` outlets

Comment: +1 Mostly agree, but I don't see why the tab controller delegate needs outlets for each view controller. The tab controller isn't going to select an invalid view controller, and it tells you which view controller it has selected, so just send a message to the controller that it tells you about (after first checking to make sure that the controller implements the method, of course).

Comment: @Caleb You have a point there. The delegate would not need outlets if it were sending the exact same message to both VCs. In my code example I need to distinguish between the two controllers because I am sending two different messages `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse`. @flouwer: Let me know if you would like me to edit my answer.

Comment: I see. Is there a real case where you'd want the tab controller delegate rather than the view controller deciding what to do when a given controller is selected? Seems like that decision belongs in each view controller.

Comment: @Caleb This is mostly theoretical, you are of course right that it is the responsibility of the VC to decide what to do. The main (or maybe the only) advantage of having the outlets is that you can send the notification messages using the concrete types, which will let the compiler check that you do the right thing. If you don't have the concrete types, you will have to send the messages using the `id` type to prevent a compiler warning.

Comment: @herzbube Very nice answer, it almost works. The only problem I'm having is connecting the self.secondViewController to the actual SecondViewController. Right now the self.secondViewController is nil, so the if comparison is not true, even if I press the second tab that displays the SecondViewController.

Comment: @herzbube I see you have said in your edit to connect outlets to SecondViewController and ThirdViewController instances. How do I do this? I'm using Storyboard. It won't let me make the connection by Ctrl dragging.

Comment: @flouwer I have never worked with storyboards before. I have just tried to solve your problem for maybe half an hour, and I must say that I am completely lost. It's probably just my missing experience, but right now I wonder how anyone can achieve anything with storyboards :-( So I'm sorry, but at the moment I can't help you with this. If you don't find the solution yourself, maybe you can ask another question on SO? I hope that I find the time to educate myself on storyboards in the next few days, but don't count on me.

Comment: @flouwer Or, as discussed with Caleb, you could just forget about the outlets. Instead implement the same method (e.g. `doSomething`) on both `SecondViewController` and `ThirdViewController`. Then change the code in `TabBarControllerDelegate` to this: `if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(doSomething)]) { [(id)viewController doSomething]; }`

Comment: OK, I used this code and it works fine! Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 5):

I too had this problem and got fed up with it. I decided to subclass `UITabBarController` and override the following methods. The reason I did both was for some reason on application launch `setSelectedViewController:` wasn't being called.

```
- (void)setSelectedIndex:(NSUInteger)selectedIndex
{
    [super setSelectedIndex:selectedIndex];
    // my code
}

- (void)setSelectedViewController:(UIViewController *)selectedViewController
{
    [super setSelectedViewController:selectedViewController];
    // my code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just dug through [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2) on storyboards, and I thought of an alternative to using `UITabBarControllerDelegate`. If you want to stick to `UITabBarControllerDelegate` then feel free to ignore this answer.

First, create a subclass of `UITabBarController`, let's call it `MyTabBarController`. In the storyboard editor you need to change the "Class" property of the tab bar controller so that the storyboard picks up your new class.

Add this code to `MyTabBarController.m`

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SecondVC"])
  {
    SecondViewController* secondViewController = (SecondViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    [secondViewController doSomething];
  }
  else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ThirdVC"])
  {
    ThirdViewController* thirdViewController = (ThirdViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    [thirdViewController doSomethingElse];
  }
}
```

In the storyboard editor, you can now select the two segues that connect to `SecondViewController` and `ThirdViewController` and change the segue identifier to "SecondVC" and "ThirdVC", respectively.

If I am not mistaken, that's all you need to do.