# Tab Bar Controller Delegate method does not gets called each time I tap on tab bar item

Tags: ios, tabbarcontroller

I've tried with Tab Bar Controller delegate method

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

implementing in a view controller and it works accordingly for the first time after launch. But when I switch to another tab item and coming back again to that specific tab item where I implemented the delegate, the delegae method does not gets called.

Why is it happening ? it suppose to call each time I tap on tab item right ? Am I doing anything wrong or what would be the proper way to do it.

Comment: Check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534330/didselectviewcontroller-does-not-get-called-on-certain-occasions

Comment: You have to show your code. (where do you set the delegate)

Comment: I have five tabs in my app. Each tab has several viewcontrollers under navigation controller. I've implemented the tabbar delegate in view controller associated with second tab.  - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
int scount =[self.navigationController.viewControllers count];
    
    if(scount>1){
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } 
}

Comment: I am using this method in AppDelegate with the UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol and it calls in every tap of the tabbar

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not setting delegate properly, If you give code or some other information the it will be easy to understand and solve problem